# what would be the efficiency of the below simple code in terms of O and how?

Tags: c, arrays

```
#define MAX 20    //defines max as 20  
#include< stdio.h>  

main()    //main function starts  
{  
    int a[MAX],i,n;  //defines a array along with some variables  `

    printf("Enter the value of n\n");    //take the size of the array from user  
    scanf("%d",&n);    //reads the value
    printf("Enter the numbers\n");    //asks to enter the values of array  
    for(i=0;i< n;i++)    //for loop is used to read the elements of the array     
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);    //reads the element    

    i=0;    //initialises i to zero to point it to the first element of array  
    do    //starts the do while loop      
    {  
        a[i]=a[i]+1;    //increases the stored value of the array by 1  
        i++;  
    } while(i< n);    //checks the while condition whether i is less than n  

    printf("The final array is \n");  
    for(i=0;i< n;i++)    //for loop is used to print the array  
        printf("%d\t",a[i]);    //prints the final array  
}
```

And will the efficiency changes if the value of i changes inside the do while loop and if it changes then how it changes.

> If the while loop is changed as below what would be the efficiency

```
int j=0;
do{
  if(j==n-2 || j==n-3)
    i--;
  else 
  {
    a[i]=a[i]++;
    i++;
    j++;
  }
} while(i< n);
```

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: You forget a comment: `#include <stdio.h> // includes stdio.h`

Comment: The efficiency is O(infinity) since you have an infinite loop.

Comment: but what if there was a `i++` between the `do{ }while()` loop?? Would it be O(3n)?

Comment: I wish they hadn't removed the homework tag. Maybe if it were applied it would just vote for the problem to be migrated to Code Reviews.

Comment: You don't check that `n <= MAX`, if someone will write number > MAX you will have a problem.

Comment: O(3n) ≡ O(n) as the Big O notation ignores constant factors.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is O(3n) = O(n) because your loop is incremented from 0 to (n-1) for 3 times..

Comment: what if the there were two if conditions where in one if condition i will be incremented and in another i will be decremented then what will be the effect on efficiency

Comment: then use a profiler and tell me. It would depend on the `if` conditions and when which of the two is executed.

Comment: if the while loop is changed as below what would be the efficiency int j=0;                                                             do{   if(j==n-2) i--;                                              else { a[i]=a[i]+1;i++;j++;}}while(i<n);

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is O(∞), because `i` is never incremented in the middle loop.

Answer (score 0):

O(n)

I think this is what you trying to write in a organize "smart" way:

```
#include< stdio.h>  
main()
{  
    int *a;
    int i;
    int n;

    printf("Enter the value of n\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    a = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(*a));//dynamically allocate the array in the needed size.
    printf("Enter the numbers\n");
    for(i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }

    for(i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        a[i]++;
    }

    for(i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d\t",a[i]);
    }
}
```